# maximum of all signs that they gave sequentially

Tags: c

Problem Statement

Harry and Larry are now bored playing with numbers. Now they want to play with plus and minus signs. This time they don’t want to give signs one by one. Anyone can give any number of signs at a time but at most N signs. Can you tell the maximum of all signs that they gave sequentially?

For example:

If the input is 7 + + - + - - - , then the answer is 3 as 3 minus signs are given sequentially and it is the maximum.
If the input is 7 + + + + + - - , then the answer is 5.
Input Format

First line will contain a positive integer N
Second line will contain N signs (+ or -)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int pcount = 1, mcount = 1, n, i;
    char str[99];
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%s", str);


    for( i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(str[i] == '+' && str[i + 1] == '+'){
           pcount++;

        } else if(str[i] == '-' && str[i + 1] == '-'){
            mcount++;

        }

    }

    if(mcount > pcount){
        printf("%d", mcount);

    } else if(pcount > mcount){
        printf("%d", pcount);
    } else {
        printf("0");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried this

input: 10
++++++++++
output should 9 but it was 10

Comment: The input you gave is 10 + signs in a row, shouldn't that output 10?

Comment: @Aaman Al Evan Is input `"7 + + - + - - - \n"` different from `"7++-+---\n`?